# java.time support for Spring Roo?

Tags: java, java-8, spring-roo, java-time

Is the Java 8 java.time api supported in Roo 2.00?
If not, is there a tutorial on how to manually swap out java.util.time/date apis and replace with java.time?
Any plans to support this in the future?
It just seems inconsistent that Spring Boot 2 is supporting 8 (dropping <8) yet this fundamental and very useful api is not included for roo 2.00.
Thx